# sqlalchemy not connecting to database file on networked file server. sqlite3 is connecting though

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Basically trying to connect a flask app to a sqlite database file on a networked windows file server using flask-sqlalchemy (fully aware of the considerations when using a sqlite database over a network.) The flask app was not connecting to the database and I was using sqlalchemy to troubleshoot.

I can connect with the following line:
`sq2_db = sqlite3.connect(r"//ppcou.ucsc.edu\Data\Archive_Data\archives_app.db")`

...but the following elicit an error:

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(r"sqlite:////ppcou.ucsc.edu\Data\Archive_Data\archives_app.db")
db.connect()
```

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(r"sqlite:///ppcou.ucsc.edu\Data\Archive_Data\archives_app.db")
db.connect()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

FYI This solves to `True`:

```
os.path.exists(r'\\ppcou.ucsc.edu\Data\Archive_Data\archives_app.db')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might need one more (!) slash. The dialect/driver prefix is `sqlite://`. The next slash is to skip the credentials and @hostname and get straight to the the database name. Then you want *two* slashes (or backslashes?!) to begin the UNC path. So by my accounting (on my fingers) that would be `sqlite://///servername/sharename/path/to/my/database.db`. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gord Thompson's comment was correct. Adding an addition slash was the remedy.

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(r"sqlite://///ppcou.ucsc.edu\Data\Archive_Data\archives_app.db")
db.connect()
```